# I wants to write a c++ program for this "Given a list of names, display the longest name." , given the array of strings and the size of array

Tags: segmentation-fault

```
    class Solution{
        public:
          string longest(string names[], int n){
           //write code here
             int len1 = names[0].length();
             cout << "length of first string is:" << len1 << endl;
             int j;
             for(int i=0 ; i<n ;i++)
             {
                if(names[i].length() > len1){
                   len1 = names[i].length();
                   j = i;
                 }
              }
              cout << names[j] ;
             }
         };

            int main()
            {

               int t;
               cout << "Number of Test Case" << endl;
               cin >> t;
               while(t--){
                int n;
                cout << "Enter the size of array" << endl;
                cin >> n;
                string names[n];
                for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                  cin >> names[i];
                Solution ob;
                cout << ob.longest(names, n)  << endl;
               }
            }
```

This code i tried but it gives segmentation fault on geeksForGeeks and on codeblocks it works but does not give any output , please help me ,  i am a beginner in c++.

Answer (score 0):

> it gives segmentation fault on geeksForGeeks

There are two obvious bugs when the size of array is `0`: `int len1 = names[0].length();` and `cout << names[j];` would both invoke undefined behavior. (This is most likely one of the test cases they feed into your program.)

In addition, allocating strings in the stack (as you do in `main()`) will cause stack overflow when `n` is large (typical stack size on Linux is 8MiB, `sizeof(std::string)` is `32` with `g++`, giving you storage for "only" 262144 strings).

P.S. Your `class Solution` serves no purpose -- `Solution::longest()` should be a stand-alone function.